# Generating random elements inside the table

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a 9x9  table. And I have filled it with some numbers.I have also highlighted the 1st row and 1st column with a `bgcolor` and it will remain fixed, i.e it doesn't get shuffled.

Here is my code:

```
<table border="2px" width="300px"id="mytable" >
<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
<td></td>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>8</td></tr>
<tr >
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">1</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>1</td><td>7</td> <td>8</td><td>3</td>
<td>2</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>1</td>
<td>6</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">3</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>8</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">4</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>3</td>
<td>8</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">5</td><td>8</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">6</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>4</td>
<td>8</td><td>7</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">7</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>8</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>2</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000">8</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>8</td><td>7</td>
<td>6</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).click(function(){
var $firstCells = $("#mytable tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:first-child)"),
    $copies = $firstCells.clone(true);

[].sort.call($copies, function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });

$copies.each(function(i){
    $firstCells.eq(i).replaceWith(this);
});

});
```

But this is working only when I click on it. How to shuffle the elements without clicking on it. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I am working with jquery

Comment: You forgot to include the jQuery that you tried which didn't work.

Comment: Look up to my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using $(function(){ ~ instead of $(document).click(function(){ ~

This will make the script run right after document is ready.